# Why is this considered going from string[] to int[]?

Tags: c#

It keeps giving me an error message here and I don't understand why.

```
int[] user31 = new int[53];
        user31 = System.IO.File.ReadLines("ratings.txt").Skip(1675).Take(53).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ReadLines returns strings, you know. It is right there in the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx

and you just do "TOArray".

If you would parse the rows before doing `ToArray`....

```
Skip(1675).Take53.Select (x=> Int.Parse(x)).ToArray()
```

(or along this line)

You would get an array of ints, but calling ToArray on an enum of string returns an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `user31` is an integer array but `ReadLine` returns `string[]`.

Try like this:

```
List<string> str =new List<string>(new string[] {"123", "234","345","456","678","678","890"});
List<int> a = str.Skip(1675).Take(53).ConvertAll(new Converter<string, int>(int.Parse));
```

No need to explicitly parse it yourself and return an array. `ConvertAll`will do the job to return an array.

**EDIT:**

Included a running test case using `ConvertAll` function.

Comment: Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the return type of `System.IO.File.ReadLines` methods. It is `String[]`.

You call Skip and Take as a result you will have an `IEnumerable<String>` calling ToArray again will give you a `String[]` not `int[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Because each line of a text file is just that, text. If you can guarantee that each line is actually an integer, you can do something like this:

```
        int[] user31 = new int[53];
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines("ratings.txt").Skip(1675).Take(53).ToArray();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            user31[i++] = Convert.ToInt32(lines[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Ok, now that is ugly code in 2013 where we have LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

ReadLines returns strings with an array

I assume that your ratings.txt file contain int values in each line
you need to convert string array to int array ..

```
    int[] user31 = new int[53];

user31= System.IO.File.ReadLines("ratings.txt").Skip(1675).Take(53).ToArray().Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
```